# Raspberry Pi 4 B NetworkManager Hotspot - limited to five connections?

Tags: wifi, pi-4, hotspot

I'm trying to connect multiple computers to a Raspberry Pi 4 B hotspot, using NetworkManager to handle the network, and I can't seem to connect more than five devices to the hotspot.

Every source I've seen has indicated that NetworkManager allows the maximum number of connections permitted by the system's hardware, and that the Raspberry Pi 4 B network adapter can handle significantly more than five connections.

I'm frankly lost, as I'm a newbie to networking. I wasn't able to find any settings in NetworkManager that would limit the number of connections, and I have no idea how to diagnose this further.

Thanks for reading, and thanks in advance to anyone who can help. If you think this question is better suited to a different exchange, let me know and I'll go there instead.

Comment: I gather there is an issue with a RAM limit in the wireless chip, maybe use a USB WiFi adapter https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3010

Comment: @CoderMike Thanks for the link, seems like a bunch of people have a similar issue. There doesn't seem to be a USB wifi adapter that meets my required number of connections, though. I believe a wifi extender will work, too, so I'll attempt that.